# How to use In-Built X-Auth-Token In Spring Security instead of Spring Session Http Cookie

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am able to generate HTTP Session Cookie with Spring Security and also able to generate X-Auth token by adding the bean for the same but not able to verify the X-Auth  token received from client side with Subsequent requests.

This is for Spring Security and Spring Session managed by Spring.

```java
    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken(); 
    }
```

Added this to generate X-Auth token

As Spring validates Spring Session id received with cookie in every request. Similarly, how we can validate the X-Auth token received from client side ?

Answer (score 0):

Add following in the controller (method) header.

```
@RequestHeader(value = "x-auth-token", required = false)  String xAuthToken
```

Validate header using code.

```
// Validate x-auth-token if it's provided
if (xAuthToken != null
    && !xAuthToken.isEmpty()
    && !request.getSession().getId().equals(xAuthToken)) {
 // Session is not valid
}else{ 
// session is valid
}
```